# SMB3 support on Mavericks

Tags: macos, network, windows, smb

Does anyone know if Mavericks supports SMB3? My work server uses it, and it's been buggy as hell and never keeps connected. If it keeps connected I lose write permissions to files I'm working on. Hoping if I use the SMB1 protocal `cifs://`

Link about it here:  http://www.tuaw.com/2013/10/27/did-mavericks-kill-your-network-drive-access-heres-a-fix/

Hope this helps someone out too with this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavericks just introduced support for SMB2.

http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#core

SMB3 is a planned feature of the next version of OS X, Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

To further this: The SMB2 support in OS X 10.9 is rather buggy. It occasionally completely locks up requiring restart. At work, we've enforced SMB1 only, which can be done either by connecting with the cifs:// protocol, but since this can be hard to enforce for non-technical users, you can also write a preference file to either `~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf` for a user preference or `/etc/nsmb.conf` for a system wide preference.

Put in either of those files the content:

```
[default]
smb_neg=smb1_only
```

And reboot. Then all connections regardless of protocol prefix, will use the SMB1 implementation.

Comment: Thanks. We just decided to implement Time Machine into our server. :)